# How to redirect a menu item to the anchor?

Tags: routes, blocks, hooks, path-aliases

I have created menu with sub-menus. The menu block is placed on the specific page.

Drupal menu path allows only allows normal path to be given to menus(like node/nid and pagepath).
I want to give path like **node/256#myblock**.

I do not want to go with contributed modules(void menu or any other) as this is for the single link in my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules are how you extend Drupal's functionality; there's very little point saying you want to achieve something without a module, as if one exists, you're just going to end up copy/pasting its code into your own module/theme anyway to get the same effect.

Drupal core has no functionality to link to an anchor, so you need to install a module which does, or copy the code from one to your own.

Whichever of those methods you decide to use, [Special Menu Items](https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) has the functionality you require (you can either install
and use it as normal, or pick the relevant bits of code out into your own module/theme).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used this module and it works for my problem.